# Using AVAudioPlayer across multiple scenes Swift and be able to adjust volume

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Hi I was wondering if there was a way to use an AVAudioPlayer across multiple scenes and change the volume. I'm currently placing it in my gameViewController which is the controller for all of my application's scenes:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let backgroundMusicURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("tempMusic.mp3", withExtension: nil)
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: backgroundMusicURL, error:nil)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay();
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play();
}
```

This works as intended, but I am unable to control its volume in the scenes themselves.

So, is there a way to have background music playing so that it runs smoothly throughout multiple scenes and the volume is still adjustable from within these scenes?

Comment: "but I am unable to control its volume in the scenes themselves" Why are you unable to do that? `backgroundMusicPlayer` is presumably an instance property; you should be able to get a reference to it and set its volume _from anywhere_.

Comment: backgroundMusicPlayer is a property of my gameviewcontroller. This means none of the scenes have access to this instance property.

Comment: Sure they do. Why wouldn't they? There is _some_ relationship between them.

Comment: The problem of "getting a reference" to an instance is the whole art of iOS programming. I can't tell you how to solve this because I don't know the relationship between them. But you do! But I can point you to my discussions of this general topic, here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_instance_references and here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_visibility_by_relationship

Comment: Just letting you guys know I haven't abandoned your help. I'm currently looking through the different urls and solutions you have given.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I got it to work using the link presented by Matt (so future viewers of this post up vote his comment).

```
if let vc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as? GameViewController{
   vc.setMusicVolume(Float(hexData.musicVolume)/100.0);
}
```

I now access the rootViewController from within the scenes themselves. I put it inside an if statement just as a precaution.

Comment: You can accept your own answer (after 48 hours?). Perfectly legal and good Stack Overflow citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the viewController with:

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController
```

That said, it is not recommended since it breaks the MVC pattern.

Comment: How does that "break MVC"? What does it even have to _do_ with MVC?